List that appears scrolled down via ScrollViewReader breaks navigation bar during transition in a NavigationStack
Starting from a NavigationStack that displays a View with a title in the inline mode, this will not have a material behind the navigation bar. If you push a View on the navigation stack now that is scrolled down programmatically via a ScrollViewReader, the background material will only appear at the end of the transition, leading to a transition animation that looks broken:

This seems to be a bug in SwiftUI as of iOS 17.5 / iOS 18 Beta 1 and I reported this as FB13973893 to Apple.
Q: Is there a workaround for this as of now?
Code to reproduce:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    ExampleListView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Show List")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Foo")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
            List(Array(1...200), id: \.self) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
            .task {
                scrollProxy.scrollTo(100, anchor: .center)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationTitle("List")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

I already tried different modifiers to trigger the scrollTo like onAppear, onChange, it's all the same. Adding a withAnimation around the scrollTo helps a little, but it still looks somewhat broken + I'd prefer to make it appear already-scrolled-down.
